# Proof of the hook length formula from Frobenius formula

Tags: representation-theory

I'm looking for a complete proof of the hook length formula for the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $S_n$ from Frobenius formula (following Fulton and Harris path) . Do you have any suggestion where I could find this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several proofs, including one using Frobenius' formula, on the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) for the hook length formula.